# Equivalent of data/services view of flash builder in intellij

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I'm currently trying to move from flashbuilder to intellij. I need the generation code which is provided by flashbuilder in the data/services tab. This view allow to generate wrapper for a service ( soap ) using the url of the webservice. Is there a feature in intellij which do the same ?

Thanks for your answer and my apologize for my english ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested, i contacted the intellij support. And they told me that there is no way inside intellij to do it for flex solution. But tools exists which do it externally of your IDE. ( flextense for example )